# How can I insert an argument like forEach, reduce and the like does?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to reinvent the wheel, sort of.. Just messing around trying to remake some jquery functions.. I've come this far

```
var ye = function (ele) {
    if (ele[0] == "#")
    {
        return document.getElementById(ele.slice(1));
    }
    else if (ele[0] == ".")
    {
        // returns an array, use index
        return document.getElementsByClassName(ele.slice(1));
    }
    else
    {
        // also returns an array
        return document.getElementsByTagName(ele);
    }
}
```

but how can I use this element as a parameter in a function in the 'ye' prototype. For example, if I wanted to make fontsize how could I get the dom element like here:

```
ye.prototype.fontSize = function (ele)
{
    ele.style.fontSize = "30px";
}
```

Just to add a bit to make the title relevant.. forEach inserts three arguments into the callback function, just like I want ye to insert ele into the fontSize function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just messing around trying to remake some jquery functions...
>
> ...but how can I use this element as a parameter in a function in the 'ye' prototype..

Here is a very crude and simple way to start...

1. Create a function with a property called `elems` which is an array and will store the selected DOM elements.

Like this:

```
var oye = function() { this.elems = []; };
```

2. On its prototype, you can create your custom functions which you want to expose. e.g. the function `fontSize` (as in your question), iterate over the `elems` array property that we created earlier changing the font size of each DOM element stored in. `this` points to the instance which is calling this function which we will ensure to be of type `oye` later on. To enable chaining, we simply return itself via `this`.

Like this:

```
oye.prototype.fontSize = function(size) {
    this.elems.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.style.fontSize = size;
    });
    return this;
};
```

3. Now create the selector function called `ye`. This serves the purpose of selecting the DOM elements, storing them in the `elems` array property of a new instance of `oye` class, and return the instance. We call the `slice` of the array prototype to convert the nodeList to an array.

Like this:

```
var ye = function(elem) {
    var newOye = new oye;
    newOye.elems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(elem));
    return newOye;
};
```

4. Now start using it in your code. Just like jQuery, you can use `ye` to select and then call your custom functions.

Like this:

```
ye("#elem1").fontSize('30px');
```

Just like jQuery, you can also chain multiple custom functions as shown in the complete working example below:

```
ye("P").fontSize('24px').dim(0.4);
```

5. Next step: Remember this is just a very crude example. You can now proceed to club the step 1 and 2 into a single call using the `init` pattern returning the new object from the selector function itseld. Learn more about Javascript and best practices.

**Here is a sample working demo**:

```js
var oye = function() { this.elems = []; };
oye.prototype.fontSize = function(size) {
    this.elems.forEach(function(elem) {
        elem.style.fontSize = size;
    });
    return this;
};
oye.prototype.dim = function(value) {
    return this.elems.forEach(function(elem) {
      elem.style.opacity = value;
    });  
    return this;
};

var ye = function(elem) {
    var newOye = new oye;
    newOye.elems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(elem));
    return newOye;
};

ye("#elem1").fontSize('30px');
ye(".elem2").fontSize('20px');
ye("P").fontSize('24px').dim(0.4);
```

```html
<div>This is normal text.</div>
<div id="elem1">size changed via id.</div>
<div class="elem2">size changed via class.</div>
<div class="elem2">size changed via class.</div>
<p>size changed and dimmed via tag name</p>
<p>size changed and dimmed via tag name</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, I may think you're new to JavaScript, or not familiar with its basic concepts. I'm not sure reinventing the wheel is a good thing in such conditions.

Since you've cited `jQuery`, you can have a look at its source code to understand how it works under the hood:

- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/core.js#L17-L23
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/core.js#L38-L81
- https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/99e8ff1baa7ae341e94bb89c3e84570c7c3ad9ea/src/core/init.js#L19-L114

Having that said, I would have done something like this:

```
var ye = function ( ele ) {
    return new ye.prototype.init(ele);
};

ye.prototype.init = function( ele ) {
    this._elements = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(ele));
    return this;
};

ye.prototype.forEach = function( fn ) {
    this._elements.forEach(fn);
    return this;
};

ye.prototype.fontSize = function( fontSizeValue ) {
    this.forEach(function (ele) {
        ele.style.fontSize = fontSizeValue;
    });
    return this;
};
```

The associated usage is as follow:

```
var myCollection = ye('.someClassName');

myCollection.forEach(function ( item, index ) {
    console.log(item.style.fontSize);
});

myCollection.fontSize('45px');

myCollection.forEach(function ( item, index ) {
    console.log(item.style.fontSize);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ye function calling before setting style, something like:

```
ye.prototype.fontSize = function(ele) {
   ye(ele).style.fontSize = '30px';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

returned object should be richer, like that:

```
var baseObject = {
    // Will be used for the element:
    element: null, 
    width: function(){ return this.element.getwidth(); /* or anything similar*/ }
    // ... Further methods
}
```

and then in your `ye` function:

```
var ye = function (ele) {
    var yeElem = clone(baseObject); // See comment below!!

    if (ele[0] == "#") { yeElem.element = document.getElementById(ele.slice(1)); }
    else if (ele[0] == "."){ /*...*/ }
    else { /*...*/ }

    return yeElem;
}
```

This way the new element has built in methods.
As for the clone() method used, it doesn't exist but you have to use some clone method.
I recommend Loadsh's `_.cloneDeep()` ([here](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep)).